# How to get who invoked a function or method?

Tags: python, reflection, introspection

This is what I need:

```
def get_invoker():
    # your magic here

# invoker.py    

def f():
    invoker = get_invoker()
    print(invoker)


# module1.py
class C(object):
    def invoke_f(self):
        f()


f()
# print <module1>

c = C()
c.invoke_f()
# print C.invoke_f
```

Is it possible? I know the modlue `inspect` has all this magic, but I've not been able to find it.

**EDIT**:

I'd like to get the function object (or the module). Not just the name.

Comment: In the last example the output should not be `invoke_f`?

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def called_function():
...     print inspect.stack()[1][3]
...
>>> def caller():
...     called_function()
...
>>> caller()
caller
```

Comment: You get a string from here. How can you get the function object?